# Constexpr function that returns ticks at compile time for profiling?

Tags: c++, profiling, timing, constexpr

I want to have a means of measuring the time it takes to execute a certain compile time function at compile time. For example

```
constexpr int64_t triangle_sum(int64_t n) {
   int64_t s = 1;
   for(int64_t i = 1; i < n; i++)
      s += i;
   return s;
}
```

I am seeking for a `constexpr` function that however returns different values each time it's called: It should return the time within in the compilation process or the current time of day, or something similar. So that I can measure and compare the "compile time" of different compile time algorithms.

Comment: " I am seeking for a `constexpr` function that however returns different values each time it's called:"  I don't think you can.  I am pretty sure that part of the definition of a `constexpr` function is that it's a pure function.

Comment: @MartinBonner is there something without constexpr that can do it?

Comment: @MartinBonner - A `constexpr` function that return different values on different calls is possible (search for "How to implement a constant-expression counter in C++"); the problem is that use a dark corner of the language, that non all compilers support it and that a simple counter is (IMHO) unuseful to respond this question.

Comment: if it is only available using compiler intrinsics, that's ok too.

Comment: @max66 : That adds another datapoint to support my assertion that the reason there is no "International Obfuscated C++ Competition" is that it would provide no intellectual challenge.  (FAOD: C++ is my favourite language - that doesn't mean I can't recognize it is excessively complicated.)

Comment: @MartinBonner - I'm completely agree with you. But C++ is my favourite language (and I found it funny) **because** it's (IMHO) excessively complicated and because I can blame the language when nobody understand my code.